# Google Cloud Run / Does domain mapping supports ALIAS records?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, mapping, alias, google-cloud-run

As it can be available on heroku (wildcard CNAME's), can google cloud run be configured with a single ALIAS type record ?

`@ 300 IN ALIAS ghs.googlehosted.com.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Run requires a CNAME Resource Record to verify the custom domain.

Cloud Run Custom Domains do not support domain wildcards. You specify a domain name, Google verifies the domain name. There are no configuration settings to support wildcards.

The actual DNS resource records are A, AAAA, and CNAME. However, Cloud Run does not care what you setup provided that the CNAME is correct for domain verification.

ALIAS records are not a standard type of DNS Resource Record. They are vendor specific, act like a CNAME and usually provide optimization of name translation. They are also used in cases where a CNAME cannot be used (zone apex). Cloud Run does not have this limitation so ALIAS records are not required.

Follow the recommended DNS configuration that Cloud Run specifies when setting up a custom domain. Anything else will most likely not be supported by Google.

Comment: Hello john, thanks for your reply. I was trying to find a way not to have to define every cnames (a.domain.com, b.domain.com, etc...). Aliases help here. Would one have to define each of these, one by one , as a cname, at the registrar ?

Comment: Cloud Run does not support your goal (a.example.com, b.example.com). You would create separate Cloud Run services, one for each unique dns name. They could share the same code, they would just have different endpoints.

Comment: Humm; thats okay for this part. The mapping would still have to be done within cloudrun (a given subdomain to map to a given service). But i don't want to define all subdomains one by one at my registrar too - so was my question

Comment: I will rewrite my question a bit i guess

Comment: You will need to follow Cloud Run's rules for custom domain names. This means creating a separate DNS entry for each unique DNS name.

Comment: Note that if you try to skip creating DNS records at your registrar, Cloud Run will refuse to issue the custom domain.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I am in a fix where I cannot host my cloud run service as a website at https://example.com using A and AAAA records. Also, CNAME records only work for sub-domains. Annoying!

Comment: @F.O.O - create a new question with details. You can use Cloud Run as your website.

Comment: @Ben did you ever figure out a workaround for this? I really don't want to go back to Compute Engine or setup Kubernetes manually... :(